# Reducibility of the Weil representation

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group, and let $G\longrightarrow \hat{G}$, $g\mapsto \chi_g$ be a group isomorphism from $G$ to its dual (i.e. the abelian group of group morphisms from $G$ to $\textbf{C}^{\times}$). We define two endormorphisms of $V=\textbf{C}[G]$ as a $\textbf{C}$-vector space by their action on $g\in G$:
$$\rho_S(g)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|G|}}\sum_{h\in G}{\overline{\chi_h(g)}h},$$
$$\rho_{T^2}(g)=\chi_g(g)g.$$
I have several questions:

1. If $\Gamma$ is the matrix group generated by $S=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $T^2=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$, does $\rho:\Gamma\longrightarrow \operatorname{GL}(V)$ defines a representation?
2. Is this the so-called Weil representation attached to $G$?
3. What do we know about the reducibility of $\rho$?

Many thanks!

Comment: The Weil representation attached to $G$ is a representation *of the Heisenberg group of $G$*, not of $G$ itself.  The Heisenberg group of $G$ contains a copy of $G$ itself, which acts on the Weil representation by translation.  A nice paper on this is [Prasad - On character values …](http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.1486)..

Comment: Ok, thanks! Actually my confusion comes from the following text http://web.stanford.edu/~tonyfeng/245C.pdf where definition 2.2.4 seems close to what I introduce in this question.

Comment: Yes, [you](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/307469/reducibility-of-the-weil-representation#comment764862_307469)'re quite right!  I'm not sure how that compares with the Weil representation as defined by Prasad.  Note that the standard reduction of a Weil representation into the even and odd subspaces works here, too, so that your representation (if it is a representation) is certainly reducible if $G$ is not the trivial group.

Comment: Isn't $S^2=-1$ the only relation of the group generated by $S$ and $T^2$? So in that case (1) is certainly true.

Comment: @WillSawin, since $S^2$ isn't in the group generated by $T^2$, I think that the only relation is $S^4 = 1$.

Comment: @LSpice My notation $S^2=-1$ was intended to denote $S^4=1$ and $S^2$ is central, so $S^2 T^2= T^2 S^2$. (Actually I worked it out for the corresponding subgroup of $PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$ and then hastily added the minus sign.)